Problem with Multipart/Form-Data Deserialization in API Platform

Title: Problem with Multipart/Form-Data Deserialization in API Platform
Body:
Hello,
I am experiencing an issue with handling multipart/form-data in my Symfony application using API Platform. When I try to add a message with an attached audio file via a form, I get an error indicating that deserialization for the "multipart" format is not supported.
Details of the Issue:
I am attempting to send a message with an audio file using a POST multipart request. Here is the error I encounter:
HttpErrorResponse
error
: {@id: '/api/errors/400', @type: 'hydra:Error', title: 'An error occurred', detail: 'Deserialization for the format "multipart" is not supported.', status: 400, …}

Here are the details of my code:
1. API Platform Configuration (api_platform.yaml):
api_platform:
    title: Hello API Platform
    version: 1.0.0
    formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        json: ['application/json']
        multipart: ['multipart/form-data']
    defaults:
        stateless: true
        cache_headers:
            vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin']
        extra_properties:
            standard_put: true
            rfc_7807_compliant_errors: true
    event_listeners_backward_compatibility_layer: false
    keep_legacy_inflector: false

2. Symfony Controller (MessageController.php):
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Message;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class MessageController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/api/messages', name: 'api_message_create', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $description = $request->request->get('description');
        $keywords = $request->request->get('keywords');
        $category = $request->request->get('category');
        
        $audioFile = $request->files->get('audioFile');

        if ($audioFile) {
            $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $audioFile->guessExtension();
            $audioFile->move($this->getParameter('audio_directory'), $filename);

            $message = new Message();
            $message->setDescription($description);
            $message->setKeywords($keywords);
            $message->setCategory($category);
            $message->setAudioFile($filename);

            $entityManager->persist($message);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->json($message, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
        }

        return $this->json(['error' => 'No file uploaded'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}

3. Angular Service (MessageService.ts):
addMessage(message: Message, audioFile?: File): Observable<Message> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    if (message.description) {
        formData.append('description', message.description);
    }
    if (message.keywords) {
        formData.append('keywords', message.keywords);
    }
    if (message.category?.['@id']) {
        formData.append('category', message.category['@id']);
    }
    if (audioFile) {
        formData.append('audioFile', audioFile, audioFile.name);
    }

    return this.http.post<Message>(this.apiUrl, formData).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
            console.error('Error adding message:', error);
            return throwError(error);
        })
    );
}

4. Error Received:
Deserialization for the format "multipart" is not supported.


By default, Symfony is not able to decode multipart/form-data-encoded data, see documentation.
As shown in the API Platform docs, you need to create your own decoder and denormalizer.
